# Spring MVC and JBehave. Cannot get @Autowired beans in *Steps.java class

Tags: spring-mvc, autowired, jbehave

I work with Spring MVC for a while, and used JUnit with it. When I tested service or dao, I used @Autowired annotation for beans injection and it works good. Please note, that I use same config files in tests and application, to avoid misconfiguration after tests runs for deployment.

Now I have to make service layer test with JBehave. My Spring MVC already have packages for domain, DAO, service layers. Also I create sample JUnit tests for DAO and service. But no luck with JBehave. I used "The five-step overview" from http://jbehave.org/, and was able to run JBehave test without @Autowired beans and it runs successfully, generated reports and so on. Now I want to add @Autowired beans from DAO and Service layer to *Steps.java, but it seems like them are not instantiated at runtime.

I also googled and looked Spring examples from http://jbehave.org/, but all I found not work, and examples from jbehave.org looks messy for me.

So for now I have working config with Spring MVC, Hibernate, JUnit, JBehave built on MAVEN in Spring Tool Suite (Eclipse). The question is: How to make work @Autowired objects in *Steps.java class for JBehave test.

I am not sure what data I have to put here, so If something insufficient please tell, I'll add it.

admin_service_story.story

```
Scenario: There is 0 in DB

Given In database there are 0 goods
When The controller calls list method of service
Then service returns with 0 elements list
```

AdminServiceStory.java // I run it as JUnit test

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration("classpath:/META-INF/spring/root-context.xml")
public class AdminServiceStory extends JUnitStory{

    private final CrossReference xref = new CrossReference();

    public AdminServiceStory() {
        configuredEmbedder().embedderControls().doGenerateViewAfterStories(true).doIgnoreFailureInStories(true)
                .doIgnoreFailureInView(true).useThreads(2).useStoryTimeoutInSecs(60);
        // Uncomment to set meta filter, which can also be set via Ant or Maven
        // configuredEmbedder().useMetaFilters(Arrays.asList("+theme parametrisation"));
    }

    @Override
    public Configuration configuration() {
        Class<? extends Embeddable> embeddableClass = this.getClass();
        Properties viewResources = new Properties();
        viewResources.put("decorateNonHtml", "true");
        // Start from default ParameterConverters instance
        ParameterConverters parameterConverters = new ParameterConverters();
        // factory to allow parameter conversion and loading from external
        // resources (used by StoryParser too)
        ExamplesTableFactory examplesTableFactory = new ExamplesTableFactory(new LocalizedKeywords(),
                new LoadFromClasspath(embeddableClass), parameterConverters);
        // add custom converters
        parameterConverters.addConverters(new DateConverter(new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd")),
                new ExamplesTableConverter(examplesTableFactory));

        return new MostUsefulConfiguration()
                .useStoryControls(new StoryControls().doDryRun(false).doSkipScenariosAfterFailure(false))
                .useStoryLoader(new LoadFromClasspath(embeddableClass))
                .useStoryParser(new RegexStoryParser(examplesTableFactory))
                .useStoryPathResolver(new UnderscoredCamelCaseResolver())
                .useStoryReporterBuilder(
                        new StoryReporterBuilder()
                                .withCodeLocation(CodeLocations.codeLocationFromClass(embeddableClass))
                                .withDefaultFormats().withPathResolver(new ResolveToPackagedName())
                                .withViewResources(viewResources).withFormats(Format.CONSOLE, Format.STATS, Format.TXT, Format.HTML, Format.XML)
                                .withFailureTrace(true).withFailureTraceCompression(true).withCrossReference(xref))
                .useParameterConverters(parameterConverters)
                // use '%' instead of '$' to identify parameters
                .useStepPatternParser(new RegexPrefixCapturingPatternParser("%"))
                .useStepMonitor(xref.getStepMonitor());
    }

    @Override
    public InjectableStepsFactory stepsFactory() {
        return new InstanceStepsFactory(configuration(), new AdminServiceSteps());
    }
}
```

AdminServiceSteps.java

I marked string with exception: goodDAO.save(good);//!!! here exception occurs java.lang.NullPointerException !!!

```
@Component
public class AdminServiceSteps {
    private static final String CATALOG_NUMBER_PREFIX = "Num_";
    private static final String NAME_PREFIX = "Good name_";
    private static final String DESCRIPTION_PREFIX = "Description_";

    @Autowired
    private AdminService adminService;

    @Autowired
    private GoodDAO goodDAO;

    List<Good> goodsList;

    @Transactional
    @Given("In database there are %num goods")
    public void putGoodsInDB(int num) {
        Good good;
        for (Integer i = 0; i< num; i++){
            good = new Good();
            good.setCatalogNumber(CATALOG_NUMBER_PREFIX+Integer.toString(i));
            good.setDescription(DESCRIPTION_PREFIX+Integer.toString(i));
            good.setName(NAME_PREFIX+Integer.toString(i));
            goodDAO.save(good);//!!! here exception occurs java.lang.NullPointerException !!!
        }
    }

    //@Transactional
    @When("The controller calls list method of service")
    public void controllerCallsList() {
        //goodsList = adminService.list();
    }

    @Then("service returns with %num elements list")
    public void checkGoodsListSize(int num) {
        //assertEquals("Assert list size", num, goodsList.size());
    }
}
```

Augusto thanks for idea. Let's look what happend. I changed

```
public class AdminServiceStory extends JUnitStory implements ApplicationContextAware {
```

and in class body:

```
...

    ApplicationContext springContext; 

    @Override
    public InjectableStepsFactory stepsFactory() {
        return new SpringStepsFactory(configuration(), springContext);
     }

    @Override
    public void setApplicationContext(ApplicationContext applicationContext)
            throws BeansException {
        springContext = applicationContext;
    }
```

When I looked at debugger, it looks like InjectableStepsFactory() runs before setApplicationContext(), so springContext variable not set yet.

so I get

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.jbehave.core.steps.spring.SpringStepsFactory.stepsTypes(SpringStepsFactory.java:32)
    at org.jbehave.core.steps.AbstractStepsFactory.createCandidateSteps(AbstractStepsFactory.java:34)
    at org.jbehave.core.embedder.StoryManager.runBeforeOrAfterStories(StoryManager.java:90)
    at org.jbehave.core.embedder.StoryManager.runStories(StoryManager.java:75)
    at org.jbehave.core.embedder.Embedder.runStoriesAsPaths(Embedder.java:203)
    at org.jbehave.core.junit.JUnitStory.run(JUnitStory.java:24)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:44)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:15)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:41)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:20)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestMethodCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestMethodCallbacks.java:74)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestMethodCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestMethodCallbacks.java:83)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.SpringRepeat.evaluate(SpringRepeat.java:72)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:233)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:87)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:193)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:52)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:191)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:42)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:184)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.java:61)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.java:71)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:236)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.run(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:176)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestReference.run(JUnit4TestReference.java:50)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:38)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:459)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:675)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:382)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:192)
```

Answer (score 2):

You're trying to use spring and JBheave in a way that I'm not familiar with and might not even be possible to make it work with quite a bit of work (and knowledge from the internals of JBehave).

There's an obvious problem in which the instance of `AdminServiceSteps` you create is not coming from the Spring context. You can try replacing the StepsFactory in this way

```
@Override
public InjectableStepsFactory stepsFactory() {
    return new SpringStepsFactory(configuration(), springContext);
}
```

The class [`SpringStepsFactory`](http://jbehave.org/reference/stable/javadoc/spring/index.html?org/jbehave/core/embedder/Embedder.html) is part of the JBehave-spring integreation

Comment: Yes, I think you right here: "the instance of AdminServiceSteps you create is not coming from the Spring context". But do not know how to do this. Anyway when I proceed I got Exception. Will make this comment detailed in first post

Comment: Try using the class I mentioned above `SpringStepsFactory`. That will use the correct instance with the autowired values.

Comment: I done it, but also get problems. Look edited part of my initial message after: "Augusto thanks for idea. Let's look what happend. I changed".